# Why does fmt.Print() returns an error if no one handles it

Tags: go, stdout

I am often tormented by the question, why does fmt.Print() return an error?

I have never met a situation where I needed it.

In [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#print(java.lang.String)) and [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print), printing to stdout usually does not returns an error.
In [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=net-6.0#System_Console_WriteLine_System_String_), printing to stdout can cause OOMException.

This, in theory, may be OOM, but there is no point in trying to write something then cause this will be an unrecoverable panic and the program most likely will be killed.

Or maybe this is necessary so that the program can understand that the exit is closed?
You can't detect if the process down the pipe has terminated without writing to it, right?

Has anyone ever had to handle this error?

Comment: There are two reasons to return an error: 1) to satisfy a signature that returns an error; or 2) because the operation might fail in some way. `fmt.Print` can fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Printing to stdout can return an error if, for instance, stdout is closed while printing. This is especially relevant if stdout is redirected to a pipe or to a file.

Most applications ignore this error though.

Comment: Is this case suitable for the fmt.Println()?
If you want to write messages to stdout, you're probably gonna want to make an encoder around os.Stdout.

Comment: Why? fmt.Print functions write to stdout.

Comment: Well, if I need to transfer a file, then I will most likely send bytes via os.Stdout.Write() rather than fmt.Print() and fmt.Println(). I can also use os.Stdout.Stat() to check that we can write something.

Comment: Stdout.Write writes bytes. Print writes strings.